# How to write SQL query for employes and department table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-ce

I have

```
employees table(id,f_name,l_name,salary,dept_id,manager_id)

departments table(id,dept_name,manager_id)
```

I want to show `dept_name`, its `manager_id`, manager's `l_name` and number of employees working under respective manager in single table.

Comment: what have you tried, also tag the question correctly, which DB are you trying to run this query against?

Comment: How can we tell if someone is a manager for the manager's last name part? I don't see a manager name column in departments nor something like a position column in employees,

Comment: Can you give some sample data so that I can test my query?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT dept.dept_name, dept.manager_id, emp.l_name, emp_count.empcount 
FROM departments AS dept 
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS empcount, manager_id FROM employees GROUP BY manager_id) AS emp_count ON dept.manager_id = emp_count.manager_id
INNER JOIN employees AS emp ON dept.manager_id = emp.id
```

OR this:

```
SELECT dept.dept_name, dept.manager_id, emp.l_name, emp_count.empcount 
FROM departments AS dept 
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS empcount, dept_id FROM employees GROUP BY manager_id) AS emp_count ON dept.dept_id = emp_count.dept_id
INNER JOIN employees AS emp ON dept.manager_id = emp.id
```

The 1st one is to reference the manager_id while the second one is to reference the dept_id. Either from the two can have the same results. I achieve this by creating a subquery for the count of employees and link this to the department.

Here's the [SQL Server 2008 Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74587/1).

Comment: `(SELECT COUNT(*) AS empcount, dept_id FROM employees GROUP BY manager_id)` this may reduce performance. hence sql server create temporary storage for this selection.

Comment: Yes but I didn't say that its the only way.

Comment: i think `correlated subquery` gave better performance in this case.. am i correct?

Comment: Yes but give the same results. Nevertheless, I answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple query however, you should probably remove the manager_id in the employees table and just use the employee record id as the identifier.

```
Select dept.dept_name, dept.manager_id, (select e.l_name from employees as e where e.id = dept.manager_id), count(select em.id from employees as em where dept.id = em.dept_id) FROM departments as dept
```

This should work however, you did not supply the specific db you are working with.  If you update your question or tell what db, I can edit to that db if it does notwork.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
    select d.deptname, d.managerid, e.fname, (select COUNT(*) 
                                            from employees 
                                            where managerid = d.managerid and 
                                            managerid <> id and
                                            depid = d.id
                                            group by managerid) NoofEmps
from departments d join employees e on d.managerid = e.id
```

Field names may be not exactly as same as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this `correlated subquery` for getting the count. rest you can select using join. This may help you

```
 SELECT  D.dept_name,
            D.manager_id,
            E.l_name,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                     FROM employees 
                     WHERE manager_id=D.manager_id) AS numberOfEmployees
 FROM   departments D INNER JOIN employees E ON D.manager_id=E.id
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is another solution you can consider

```
SELECT D.dept_name as [Department Name],
E.manager_id as [Manager ID],
E.l_name as [Last Name],
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees EM WHERE EM.manager_id = E.id) as [Employee Count]
FROM departments D
INNER JOIN employees E on D.manager_id = E.manager_id
```